# Idempotentency of GET verb in an RESTful API

Tags: rest, get, idempotent

As it was mentioned here https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/ (and in other places as well):

> GET APIs should be idempotent, which means that making multiple
>   identical requests must produce same result everytime until another
>   API (POST or PUT) has changed the state of resource on server.

How to make this true in an API that return time for example? or that return data that is affected by time.

In other words, each time I use `GET http://ip:port/get-time-now/`, it is going to return a different response. However, I did not send any `POST` or `PUT` between two sequenced `GET's`

Does this make the previous statement wrong? Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idempotency is a promise to clients/intermediaries that the request can be reissued in case of network failures or the like without any further considerations and not so much that the data will never change.

If you take a `POST` request for example, in case of a network failure you do not know if the previous request reached the server but the response got lost midway or if the initial request didn't even reach the server at all. If you re-issue the request you might create a further resource actually, hence `POST` is not idempotent. `PUT` on the other side has the contract that it replaces the current representation with the one contained in the request. If you send the same request twice the content of the resource should be the same after any of the two `PUT` requests was processed. Note that the actual result can still differ as the service is free to modify the received entity to a corresponding representation. Also, between sending the data via `PUT` and retrieving it via `GET` a further client could have updated the state in between, so there is no guarantee that you will actually receive the exact representation you've sent to the service.

Safetiness is an other promise that only `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` supports. It promises the invoker that it wont modify any state at all hence clients/intermediaries are safe on issuing such request without having to fear that it will modify any state. In practice this is an important promise to crawlers which blindly invoke any URLs in order to learn their content. In case of violating such promises, i.e. by deleting data while processing a `GET` request the only one to blame is the service implementor but not the invoker. If a crawler invokes such URLs and hence removes some data it is not the crawlers fault actually but only the service implementor.

As you have a dynamic value in your response, you might want to prevent caching of responses though as otherwise intermediaries might return an old state for your resource

Answer (score 0):

The main basic concept of **idempotent** and **safe** methods of HTTP:-

**Idempotent Method:-** The method can called multiple times with same input and it produce same result.

**Safe Method:-** The method can called multiple times with same input and it doesn't modify the resource onto the server side.

Http methods are categorized into following 3 groups-

1. GET,HEAD,OPTIONS are **safe** and **idempotent**
2. PUT,DELETE are **not safe** but **idempotent**
3. POST,PATCH are **neither safe** & **nor idempotent**