# How does concepts idempotent and safe methods differ?

Tags: rest, http, server, idempotent

Trying to understand the core concept of idempotent and safe methods, but I didn't get clarity. As per my analysis

- Idempotent methods - can called multiple times with same input and it produce same result.
- Safe methods - doesn't modify the resource in server side.

Http Methods are categorized as follows.

- GET,HEAD,OPTIONS are safe and idempotent
- PUT,DELETE are not safe but idempotent
- POST,PATCH are neither safe nor idempotent

Help me understand with more details w.r.t internal mechanism of HTTP methods on server side and how safe differ from idempotent

Is there any other characteristics available to describe the  idempotent and safe methods other than resource modification and product same result.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/what-are-idempotent-and-safe-methods-of-HTTP-and-REST.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idempotentency of GET verb in an RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403177/idempotentency-of-get-verb-in-an-restful-api)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49403942/7930622

Comment: Is there any characteristic available to describe the idempotent and safe methods other than resource modification and produce same result. May be in server side can we describe with server level cache and etc..

Comment: too broad Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Both idempotency and saftiness are just promisses to clients how a request should be processed by the server. There are no internal mechanisms to guarantee these kind of promisses. If someone modifies resource state via processing GET requests he simply violates the protocol and risks of breaking interoperability rules with other clients that perform their actions based on the outlined semantics in the protocol.

Comment: @RomanVottner: I got your point, it gives me more clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Help me understand with more details w.r.t internal mechanism of HTTP methods on server side and how safe differ from idempotent

Both [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) and [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) describe the semantics of handling a request.

> Request methods are considered "safe" if their defined semantics are essentially read-only; i.e., the client does not request, and does not expect, any state change on the origin server as a result of applying a safe method to a target resource.

Safe methods are queries, in the [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) sense - they don't change anything, they typically include a read of the state of the resource, but not a modification of the state of the resource.

Safe request handling leaves the resource in the same state, so a safe method is necessarily also idempotent.

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is the same as the effect for a single such request.

What idempotent request handling means is that if a client sends a request, and doesn't get an answer, the client can *repeat* the request.

Idempotent request handling basically means that the server calculates the final state of the resource from the request alone (without considering the current state of the resource).  When handling the message a second time, the same new state will be calculated and applied.

This is roughly analogous to assigning a value.

```
          // the previous value of x was 10, say
set(x, 7) // and now the value of x is 7
set(x, 7) // and now the value of x is still 7
```

In HTTP, the methods [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) and [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) are defined to have idempotent  semantics.  Notice what these methods have in common: the client knows what the final state of the resource should be, and is asking the server to make it happen.

If your handling of a request instead is analogous to

```
                // the previous value of x was 10, say
increment(x, 7) // and now the value of x is 17
increment(x, 7) // and now the value of x is 24
```

then your handling of the request is not idempotent.

Note that it is the *semantics* that are important here.  Here's what [Fielding had to say in 2002](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe. What it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the sake of this definition).

Answer (score 0):

SAFE Methods - doesn't change any resource in a server.
Example : GET, OPTIONS.

IDEMPOTENCY Methods - doesn't change state of a server even with identical request for multiple time.
Example: GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
All SAFE methods are IDEMPOTENT and not vice versa